# How can I make this redux function more efficient?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, redux-reducers

My initial version did not use cloning.  However `useSelector()` was not firing until I added another clone statement.

I thought that by cloning the containing object on a state change this would cause it tor fire.  Particularly this line here.

```
  let newState = { ...state };
```

That is a sub question.  Why does not returning a new state cause useSelector to fire.

I had to add a second clone to get it to fire as follows:

```
const clone = [...newState.messages];
```

I find this behavior odd, and wonder if it might be a bug.  Also not very efficient to have to clone my messages array.

The complete reducer is as follows:

```
const Messages = (state = {messages: false}, action) => {
  let newState = { ...state };
  switch(action.type) {
  case 'initializeMessages':
    newState.messages = action.messages;
    return newState;
  case 'addMessage':
    // cloning is required to make useSelector() fire
    const clone = [...newState.messages];
    clone.unshift(action.message);
    newState.messages = clone;
    return newState;
  }
  return state;
};
```

and I use it as follows:

**Updating**

```
  const messages = useSelector( (state) => state.Messages.messages );
```

**Dispatching**

```
dispatch({type: 'addMessage', message: message});
```

**UPDATE**

After updating to hooks, my reduces don't work anymore unless I clone embedded arrays.  Before I did not have to do this:

Comment: Spreading into an object is a shallow copy.

Answer (score 0):

you are right, you need to do the same for `addMessage` block like:

```
const newState = {
    ...state,
    messages: [
        ...newState.messages,
        action.message
    ]
};
```